# Construct a list from another list

Tags: list-manipulation, permutation

Given a list, `lst`, of length 2n, I want to construct a new one that results from the exchange of the fist half of `lst` with the second half of `lst` with sign change. E.g. given

```
lst = Range[24]
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, \
18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24} *)
```

then I want the new list to be

```
{24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, \
-6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12}
```

I can do it like

```
Flatten[{lst[[-Range[12]]], -lst[[Range[12]]]}]
(* {24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, -1, -2, -3, \
-4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12} *)
```

but I guess there are more elegant ways.

Comment: `Flatten@MapThread[#1@#2 &, {{Reverse, Minus}, Reverse@Partition[Range[24], 12]}]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way, but I'll leave you to judge elegance.

```
Join[Reverse@#2, -#] & @@ Partition[lst, Length[lst]/2]
```

> {24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12}

Comment: According to Mathematica precedence rules, `Length@lst/2` is equivalent to `(Length@lst)/2`

Comment: @andre Yes.  Perhaps I should have written `Length[lst]/2` for clarity.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes I'm convinced that it would be better to write `Length[lst]/2`(I'm thinking of people who don't have Mathematica available, or those who are not aware that multi-click is very fine to see precedence of terms)

Comment: @andre As you can see I have already taken your advice and edited the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Your way is pretty good as it stands.  We can eliminate some of the intermediate lists:

```
Join[lst[[-1 ;; -12 ;; -1]], -lst[[;; 12]]]
```

We can also generalize slightly:

```
Length[lst]/2 // Join[lst[[-1 ;; -# ;; -1]], -lst[[;; #]]] &
```

Answer (score 4):

```
lst = Range[20];

Join[Reverse@Take[#[[1]], #[[2]]], -Drop[#[[1]], #[[2]]]] &@{lst, -Length[lst]/2}

 (*{20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, -6, -7, -8, -9, -10}*)
```

Comment: +1. also: `Join[Reverse@Take[##], -Drop[##]] &[lst, -Length[lst]/2]`

Answer (score 3):

```
TakeDrop[lst, 12] /. {x_, y_} :> Flatten[{Reverse@y, -x}]
```

> {24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13, -1, -2, -3, -4, -5, 
>   -6, -7, -8, -9, -10, -11, -12}